# AngularJS - View not updating with new array

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have an array which loads old data on page load.
However, this is not being loaded by angularJS. 
It seems my controller is being called twice.

Here's the code

```
$scope.searchTerms = JSON.parse(APIDataService.loadLocalData('changedSearchTerm'));
var totalPages = JSON.parse(APIDataService.loadLocalData('oldData'));
var getOldDataOn = APIDataService.getOldData($scope.searchTerms, totalPages, 1)
    .then(function(data) {
            if(data.thumbpath.length > 0)
            {
                console.log('records found');
                $scope.hasResults = true;
                $scope.records = data.thumbpath;                           
            } else {
                $scope.hasResults = false;
            }
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log('Image retrieval failed.')
        });
```

For some reason, console.log($scope.records) shows records, but Angular view is not being updated. I also tried $scope.$apply, but it's not working.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post your view code as well?

Comment: Are you sure you're binding it correctly in your view? What "type" is data.thumbpath ? Why isn't `$scope.$apply()` not working, and how did you try to invoke it? I think a little more context is needed here to help you. Pls post the template, and a little more info..

Comment: @gillyb I don't think $scope.$apply() is necessary.

Comment: I'm curious to see what you are doing with $scope.records and also how you are using your controller.

Comment: Show the important part of your template/html of the controller. It seems that the error should be there.

Comment: Here's the service which is getting data from the Laravel Backend
https://pastebin.com/JxLs5ARc

Here's HTML Code
https://pastebin.com/56CGqxbJ

data.thumbpath is an array returned from Laravel backend. I have no idea why $scope.$apply is not working. When I search, I get normal response, but doing a call on beginning of controller is not working.

Comment: Here's entire controller, for reference
https://pastebin.com/whAjMkgD

Comment: @JonathanAnctil I don't either, I was just trying to demonstrate that we need more details and context to be able to help properly... From the details in the question, it can be a few different problems.

Comment: I've uploaded full code, please have a look. When I do console.log($scope.records) after the call, I get records but initially it's empty. I also did $scope.$apply() after the call, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can someone please help?
I've added my full code to https://github.com/kirobo/AngularApp